# How to delete the selected record from listview on Listview Delete Command?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

Can anybody know hows to remove the selected row when i click on delete button of selected item in listview ?

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you looked at other questions here, and had other problems? Your question currently needs a lot more information to be answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass command argument with the delete button, get the command argument from code behind file in itemcommand event check for the button command name and then delete the row.